# Data not inserting in database when using console application

Tags: c#, database-connection, console-application

I am new to console application. Now i wrote a sample function for insert values in database. There is no problem in my database connection. But my valuse are not inserting in table. Please find the issue and let me know.

This is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
try
            {
                string sConnectionString = "Data Source=my ipaddress;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=db;user id=user;Password=password";
                string sSQL = "";
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("OK");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                    {

                        sSQL = "INSERT INTO test " +
                         "(id) " +
                             "VALUES (" + i + ")";

                        Console.WriteLine(i + " inserted successfully");

                    }
                    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection);
                }
            }
            catch (DbException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOT OK");
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the _problem_ exactly? You get error or exception message? Unexpected result? What?

Comment: This is because you don't execute `objCmd` at all. Actually, this is clear, if you will use debugger.

Comment: no error. my code doesn't go catch block. But values are not inserting in database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not executing the command at all - you're creating a `SqlCommand`, and then doing nothing with it. You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

However, you should *also* stop building the SQL like that. You should start using parameterized SQL *right now*. Something like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var sql = "INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (@id)";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        // Adjust this to match the type of the id field
        var parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            parameter.Value = i; 
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Altough it is necessary to use *parameterized query* but this one is not vulnerable to SQL Injection. Right?

Comment: @user2946329: Well, see http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/ - better to be safe than sorry, I'd say. (It's possible that with only positive values, it *may* be safe - but it's still a really bad idea. Why get into bad habits?)

Comment: So it's safe not parameterize an SQL query when the parameter is not a string, but it's a terrible habit to get into. Yes *parameterized query* should be the way to go and I've recommend it always.

Comment: @user2946329: No, it's not safe to not parameterize a SQL query when the parameter isn't a string. For `DateTime` values you stand a significant risk of data loss, and even for numbers there's the possibility of problems - especially for floating point numbers, where the local decimal separator may not be what the database expects.